# Deleting items with AJAX is reloading my page

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

So I have a list of content generated by a table in SQL + an external API. This is how I fetch the content:

```
 for(i=0; i<userLiked.length; i++){

        let API_URL = `https://api.rawg.io/api/games/${userLiked[i]}?key=MY-API-KEY`;

            fetch(`${API_URL}`)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then(res=>{
                console.log(res);
                likedGamesList.innerHTML += `<li class="likedGameCard" style="background-color: #${res.dominant_color}"><h3>${res.name}</h2><img src="${res.background_image}" class="gameImage">
                <form method="post" action="remove.php" class="removeBtnForm">
                <input type="text" name="liked" class="removeInput" value="${res.id}" style="display: none">
                <button type="submit" class="removeBtn">Remove</button></form></li>`;
            })
}
```

This is the PHP to delete rows of the table:

```
<?php

    $started = session_start();
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','password','db');
    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection Failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];

    $like = isset($_POST["liked"] ) ? $_POST["liked"]: '';

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM likes WHERE userId = ? AND gameId = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $userId, $like);
        $execval = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();

?>
```

And this is the JS file to make the AJAX request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".removeBtnForm").submit(function (event) {
    var liked = $(this).children(".removeInput").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "remove.php",
      data: { liked: liked },
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

When the user clicks into the delete button, the row gets successfully removed, but "remove.php" loads, so using an AJAX call with a "event.preventDefault()" at the end is not working.

I swear I have been in a million pages around here to figure out what's going wrong in my code, but I can't find the point.

Comment: Looks like you'll have lots of forms with the same ID. Since IDs must, by definition,  be unique, that isn't valid and JS will ignore all copies except one. Use a class instead

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @ADyson. Just changed IDs for classes and altered the variable "liked" to be more specific. Clicking into "remove" still loads remove.php instead of staying.

Comment: Check the console and use the js debugger to check if the event handler is actually triggered

Comment: Next issue I think is cos the forms are being loaded dynamically via fetch, when you try to bind the event to them, there's no form there to bind to yet. Look up dynamic event binding using jquery

Comment: You're my best friend now @ADyson! Changing the jQuery call to a dynamic event binding made it work. I'm changing the code in the OP in case it helps in the future. Thanks a million!

Comment: Glad it helped. But no, don't do that,keep the old code and write an Answer as well, below. That's how stackoverflow works. No one looking for solutions will find this post right now because, to a search engine, it appears to have no answer. The answer isn't part of the question! See also the [tour] for a reminder of the stackoverflow structure.